# Perl - Value of variable not working in a condition

Tags: perl, variables, conditional-statements

I created this function.

When I print my variable `my $bios_current`, it shows `$VAR1 = '200';`
But my condition `if ( $bios_current->responseCode() ne 200)` considers that it is not 200.

Could you help me ? Is it a type problem ?

```
sub check_thermalshutdown_settings {
  my $host = shift;
  if ($host->get_property('summary.hardware.model') eq "ProLiant DL360 Gen9") {
    my $error="";
    my $bios="";
    try {
      my $ilo = get_ilo_address($host->name);
      my $client = REST::Client->new();
      $client->setHost("https://$ilo");
      $client->addHeader("Authorization", "Basic blabla==");
      eval {
        local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { };
        alarm 3;
        #$client->GET("/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Bios/");
        my $bios_current = $client->GET("/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Bios/");
        print Dumper $bios_current->responseCode;
        alarm 0;
      };
      if ( $bios_current->responseCode() ne 200) {
        $bios = "none";
        $error = "Redfish API returned code ".$client->responseCode();
        print Dumper $client->responseCode();
        } else {
        my $json = decode_json($client->responseContent());
        #print Dumper $client->responseContent();

        #$bios = $json->{'Bios'}->{'Settings'}->{'ThermalShutdown'};
        $bios = $json->{'ThermalShutdown'};
        #print Dumper $bios;
        print Dumper $json->{'ThermalShutdown'};
        print "API call is ok\n";
        print  Dumper  $client->setHost("https://$ilo");

      }
    } catch {
      $bios = "none";
      $error=$_;
    };
```

Comment: @toolic I'm sorry, I'm a begginer in perl, I'm using an existant script and just added $client->GET("/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Bios/");   into a variable... I don't know how to use warnings :/

Comment: @toolic it does't work. Maybe it is an issue with the type ? or there is something specific to know about the response code API ?

Comment: I think that my $bios_current  is not equal to  `print Dumper $bios_current->responseCode;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem has nothing to do with type.

The first thing every Perl coder should learn is the following two statements should appear at the top of every script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

These two statements catch a multitude of errors one of which is the cause of your problem.

If you take a look at your eval block

```
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { };
    alarm 3;
    #$client->GET("/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Bios/");
    my $bios_current = $client->GET("/redfish/v1/Systems/1/Bios/");
    print Dumper $bios_current->responseCode;
    alarm 0;
};
```

You will see that the variable $bios_current is introduced with the `my` modifier this restricts the lifetime of the variable to the current scope, in this case the eval block.

So by the time your if statement is run the variable no longer exists and Perl helpfully creates a new empty one for you, Perl then tries to call responseCode() on the empty variable, this fails and normally would terminate the program, however you are inside a try() block at this point so instead of displaying the error the code jumps to the catch bloc instead.

Comment: @chriswh although your fix causes the program to work with out knowing what `my` does and not using `use strict` and `use warnings` you leave yourself open to many more fruitless hours of debugging.

Comment: Yes, I keep a note about strict and warnings. I'm going to check them out. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @chriswh, If this answers your question, please click the checkmark next to it.